# union and eager loading with eloquent in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, union, eager-loading

I have a table `Uuids` which has a morph relation with `dealers, masterdealers, admins and customers` table. I need to get the email addresses from all the above mentioned user types tables along with their uuids from the uuids table. i'm using union to get all the emails from dealers, masterdealers, admins and customers table but I want to somehow eagerload their uuids too.

my desired output would be something like this :

```
{
    email: 1@example.com
    uuid: 1
}, {
    email: 2@example.com
    uuid: 5
}, {
    email: 3@example.com
    uuid: 11
}
```

I have tried:

```
DB::select("SELECT email FROM customers
    UNION SELECT email FROM dealers
    UNION SELECT email FROM masterdealers
    UNION SELECT email FROM admins");
```

and it gives me all the emails from these 4 tables.

Comment: What have you tried already? Please share your code

Comment: Please add it into your answer so we can keep all the information in 1 place

Comment: @Derek i have added it to the question

Comment: Have you tried this instead: `SELECT email, uuid FROM ...`

Comment: Also, it would make more sense to use a numeric ID for each user, as what happens if a user needs to change his/her email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join your morph table with in order to get uuids for your different models

```
SELECT u.uuid,c.email 
FROM customers c
JOIN Uuids u ON c.id = u.some_mapped_col AND u.some_morph_col = 'Model Name'
UNION
SELECT u.uuid,d.email FROM dealers d
JOIN Uuids u ON d.id = u.some_mapped_col AND u.some_morph_col = 'Model Name'
UNION
SELECT u.uuid, m.email FROM masterdealers m
JOIN Uuids u ON m.id = u.some_mapped_col AND u.some_morph_col = 'Model Name'
UNION 
SELECT u.uuid, a.email FROM admins a
JOIN Uuids u ON a.id = u.some_mapped_col AND u.some_morph_col = 'Model Name'
```

Also to run raw queries in laravel you might need `DB::raw('.....')`